# Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular-material, jestjs

Getting Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined on fixture.detectChanges() method.

I am running test cases with the Jest and angular version 8
Note:  my other test cases working fine so no configuration mistake

Test.spec.ts

```
let requestListModel= new InvoicesRequestsListModel();
const initialState: InvoicesState = {
requestModel: new InvoicesRequestModel(),
requestListModel: new InvoicesRequestsListModel()
};


const tab: InvoiceResponse[] = [{
totalRecords: 1,
recordsReturned: 1,
invoices:  [{
supplier: "Test Supplier",
invoiceId:"3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66af11",
}];

requestListModel.updateTableData(tab)

let invoiceStoreStub: Partial<InvoicesStore> = {
store: {
    requestModel: new InvoicesRequestModel(),
    requestListModel: requestListModel,
},
store$:  new BehaviorSubject<InvoicesState>(initialState).asObservable(),
setInvoiceState: jest.fn(),
setRequestListModel: jest.fn(),
setRequestModel: jest.fn(),
};

describe('TradeInvoicesComponent', () => {
let fixture: ComponentFixture<TradeInvoicesComponent>;
let component: TradeInvoicesComponent;
let stubInvoiceService: InvoicesStore;
let selectMenu: SelectMenuTestHelper;

beforeEach(async(() => {
    const configure: ConfigureFn = testBed => {
        testBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [TradeInvoicesComponent],
            imports: [HttpClientTestingModule, SharedModule, MatTableModule, BrowserAnimationsModule],
            schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
            providers: [MatSnackBar, { provide: InvoicesStore, useValue: invoiceStoreStub }]
        });
    };

    configureTests(configure).then(testBed => {
        fixture = testBed.createComponent(TradeInvoicesComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        stubInvoiceService = testBed.get(InvoicesStore);
        fixture.detectChanges();
        component.dataModel.updateTableData(tab);
    });

}));
```

componat.ts

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-trade-invoices',
templateUrl: './trade-invoices.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./trade-invoices.component.scss']
})
export class TradeInvoicesComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
@ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: false}) paginator: MatPaginator;
@ViewChild(MatSort, {static: false}) sort: MatSort;
@ViewChild('input', {static: false}) input: ElementRef;
@ViewChild(MatTable, {static: true}) table: MatTable<[]>;

@Output() paginate: EventEmitter<InvoicesRequestsListModel> = new EventEmitter();
@Output() request: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
@Input() setSpinner: boolean;
public dataModel: InvoicesRequestsListModel = new InvoicesRequestsListModel();
    displayedColumns: string[] = ['status', 'invoiceId', 'supplier', 'modifieddate'];
public uiPageNumber = 0;

private invoice: Invoice;


constructor(public store: InvoicesStore,
                        private paymentConsumerService: PaymentConsumerService, private 
 _snackBar: MatSnackBar) {

}

ngOnInit() {
    this.dataModel.updateDataModel('pageNumber', this.apiPageNumber);
    this.paginate.emit(this.dataModel);
}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.store.store$.subscribe((invoice: InvoicesState) => {
        this.table.renderRows();
    });
    this.sort.sortChange.subscribe(() => {
        const sortOrder = `${this.sort.active} ${this.sort.direction}`;
        this.changeSort(sortOrder);
    });
}
```

can anyone please suggest the changes and mistake.

LONG LOGS

Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (ng:///DynamicTestModule/TradeInvoicesComponent.ngfactory.js:104:47)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (/packages/core/src/view/services.ts:410:19)
    at checkAndUpdateView (/packages/core/src/view/view.ts:368:12)
    at callViewAction (/packages/core/src/view/view.ts:615:11)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (/packages/core/src/view/view.ts:580:9)
    at checkAndUpdateView (/packages/core/src/view/view.ts:360:3)
    at callViewAction (/packages/core/src/view/view.ts:615:11)
    at execComponentViewsAction (/packages/core/src/view/view.ts:559:7)
    at checkAndUpdateView (/packages/core/src/view/view.ts:370:3)
    at callViewAction (/packages/core/src/view/view.ts:615:11)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (/packages/core/src/view/view.ts:580:9)
    at checkAndUpdateView (/packages/core/src/view/view.ts:360:3)
    at callViewAction (/packages/core/src/view/view.ts:615:11)
    at execComponentViewsAction (/packages/core/src/view/view.ts:559:7)
    at checkAndUpdateView (/packages/core/src/view/view.ts:370:3)
    at callViewAction (/packages/core/src/view/view.ts:615:11)
    at execComponentViewsAction (/packages/core/src/view/view.ts:559:7)
    at checkAndUpdateView (/packages/core/src/view/view.ts:370:3)
    at callWithDebugContext (/packages/core/src/view/services.ts:630:23)
    at Object.debugCheckAndUpdateView [as checkAndUpdateView] (/packages/core/src/view/services.ts:347:10)
    at ViewRef_.detectChanges (/packages/core/src/view/refs.ts:261:16)
    at ComponentFixture._tick (//packages/core/testing/src/component_fixture.ts:107:28)
    at packages/core/testing/src/component_fixture.ts:120:36
    at ZoneDelegate.Object..ZoneDelegate.invoke (/PROJECT/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:391:26)
    at AsyncTestZoneSpec.Object..AsyncTestZoneSpec.onInvoke (/PROJECT/node_modules/zone.js/dist/async-test.js:106:39)
    at ProxyZoneSpec.Object..ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (/PROJECT/node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:126:39)
    at ZoneDelegate.Object..ZoneDelegate.invoke (/PROJECT/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:390:52)
    at Object.onInvoke (/packages/core/src/zone/ng_zone.ts:273:25)
    at ZoneDelegate.Object..ZoneDelegate.invoke (/PROJECT/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:390:52)
    at Zone.Object..Zone.run (/PROJECT/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:150:43)
    at NgZone.run (/packages/core/src/zone/ng_zone.ts:171:50)
    at ComponentFixture.detectChanges (/packages/core/testing/src/component_fixture.ts:120:19)
    at /PROJECT/s/chocolate-demo/src/app/trade/trade-invoices/test.spec.ts:82:12
    at ZoneDelegate.Object..ZoneDelegate.invoke (/PROJECT/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:391:26)
    at AsyncTestZoneSpec.Object..AsyncTestZoneSpec.onInvoke (/PROJECT/node_modules/zone.js/dist/async-test.js:106:39)
    at ProxyZoneSpec.Object..ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (/PROJECT/node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:126:39)
    at ZoneDelegate.Object..ZoneDelegate.invoke (/PROJECT/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:390:52)
    at Zone.Object..Zone.run (/PROJECT/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:150:43)
    at /PROJECT/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:910:34
    at ZoneDelegate.Object..ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (/PROJECT/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:423:31)
    at AsyncTestZoneSpec.Object..AsyncTestZoneSpec.onInvokeTask (/PROJECT/node_modules/zone.js/dist/async-test.js:90:25)
    at ProxyZoneSpec.Object..ProxyZoneSpec.onInvokeTask (/PROJECT/node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:157:39)
    at ZoneDelegate.Object..ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (/PROJECT/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:422:60)
    at Zone.Object..Zone.runTask (/PROJECT/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:195:47)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (/PROJECT/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:601:35)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at resolvePromise (/PROJECT/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:852:31)
    at /PROJECT/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:917:17
    at ZoneDelegate.Object..ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (/PROJECT/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:423:31)
    at AsyncTestZoneSpec.Object..AsyncTestZoneSpec.onInvokeTask (/PROJECT/node_modules/zone.js/dist/async-test.js:90:25)
    at ProxyZoneSpec.Object..ProxyZoneSpec.onInvokeTask (/PROJECT/node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:157:39)
    at ZoneDelegate.Object..ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (/PROJECT/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:422:60)
    at Zone.Object..Zone.runTask (/PROJECT/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:195:47)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (/PROJECT/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:601:35)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)

Comment: I'm pretty the stack trace of error would have some useful information

Comment: @IAfanasov logs added

Answer (score -1):

Looks like this error happens in the HTML of the component `TradeInvoicesComponent`. Probably there is a usage of the `replace` function on some property and this property is not defined. Try to find `.replace` in the `trade-invoices.component.html`